# DataTables search and sort when using server processing

Tags: datatables

I have a project in which I'm planning to use Datatables to display dataset which over time grow very big. Was looking into the possibility of using server-side processing for the same. In order to optimize the calls to server I'm using the following pipeline example [Official Pipeline example](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html). Currently the data set is about 100 points.

How can the following be done

1. When pagination is set, fetch data from server and cache it using the pipeline example (server-side processing behaviour)
2. If all the data is cached, do search/sort locally similar to client side processing (client-side processing behaviour)
3. Also can (1) to (2) be achieved without loosing detched data ?

Answer (score 0):

The [Official example of Reduced Ajax through pipelining data](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/pipeline.html) can very well be used.
You need to set `"serverSide": false,` as long as you have small dataset.

Comment: My initial thought is that I would first need have the datatables in server processing mode. And in the pipeline figure if the dataset is small or not. Then change the Datatable option to client side processing. Its possible I guess. In order to change the Datatables option `"serverSide : false"`, is the datatable need to destroyed ?

Comment: However I would need pagination to work from server. Let me re-phrase the question